# Field 'id' expected a number but got ' '

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get my item's id so I can save it in the user's profile. However, when I make the post request I get the error: Field 'id' expected a number but got ''.

So how can I solve this so I can get the item's id and why is it not working in my code?

This is the view of that page:

```
def search(request):
  animes = []

  if request.method=='POST' and 'search' in request.POST :
      animes_url = 'https://api.jikan.moe/v3/search/anime?q={}&limit=6&page=1'
      
      search_params = {
          'animes' : 'title',
          'q' : request.POST['search']
          
          }

      r = requests.get(animes_url, params=search_params)
      results = r.json()
      
      results = results['results']
      
      
      if len(results):
          for result in results:
              animes_data = {
                  'Id' : result["mal_id"],
                  'Title' : result["title"],
                  'Episodes' : result["episodes"],
                  'Image' : result["image_url"]
              }
              animes.append(animes_data)
      else:
          message = print("No results found")
      
      for item in animes:
          id = item.get("Id")  
          title = item.get("Title")
          episodes = item.get("Episodes")
          image = item.get("Image")
          
          anime_in_database = Anime.objects.filter(title=title).exists()
          if not anime_in_database:
             anime = Anime.objects.create(mal_id=id, title=title, episodes=episodes, image=image) 
             anime.save()

      context = {
       'animes' : animes
       }
           
      return render(request,'search.html', context)

  elif request.method=='POST' and 'anime_pk' in request.POST :

      anime_id = request.POST.get("anime_pk")
      anime = Anime.objects.get(id = anime_id)
      request.user.profile.animes.add(anime)
      messages.success(request,(f'{anime} added to wishlist.'))
      return redirect ('/search')
   
      animes = Anime.objects.all()
   
  return render(request,'search.html')
```

The html part with the items:

```
<form method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       <section>
         <div class=row>
         <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
           <div class="card">
             
             <div class="card-body text-center">
               <p class="card-title"> <b>{{anime.Title}}</b></p>
               <hr>
               <p class="card-text">Episodes: <b>{{anime.Episodes}}</b></p>
               
               <img src = {{anime.Image}} />
               
             </div>
           </div>
       </section>
       <input type="hidden" value="{{anime.pk}}" name="anime_pk">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="font-size:18px; border-radius: 50%">★</button>
                                         
     </form>
```

The urls in my app:

```
app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
   path("", views.homepage, name="homepage"),
   path("login", views.login_request, name="login"),
   path("register", views.register_request, name="register"),
   path("logout", views.logout_request, name= "logout"),
   path("profile", views.profile, name="profile"),
   path("search", views.search, name="search")
   
]
```

Comment: Can you add your urls.py and your view signature?

Comment: @Guillaume I added the urls and the complete view of that page.

Comment: Have you printed the value of anime_pk ? Is it an empty string ?

Comment: @Guillaume It doesn't seem to be returning it anywhere but I did notice this in the traceback: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: And in the template ? Can you display the value of `{{anime.pk}}`?

Comment: @Guillaume Okay, since anime.pk didn't display anything I changed it to anime.Id and now it works. Thank you for your questions, they helped me figure it out.